# Is there any callback need to setstate in pubnub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pubnub

I have set setstate in pubnub with data and uuid but when request coming from mobile end at my web end then getting error

> Pubnub::Event: Error while calling callback `#<NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass>`

```ruby
$pubnub.set_state(channel: channel, state: state, uuid: uuid) do |envelope|
    puts envelope.status 
end
```

Comment: PubNub SDK/version and sample code if you can provide.

Comment: Pubnub SDK version is 4.0.0.Here is sample code: $pubnub.set_state(channel: channel, state: state, uuid: uuid) do |envelope|
      puts envelope.status
end

Comment: Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: It is working properly from server to mobile end but not working during mobile to server end.

Comment: Can you give an example so that I could follow that?

Comment: Please provide your full code that reproduces the issue on the mobile client and/or enable PN logging, reproduce it, and send us logs. Not sure which mobile PubNub SDK you are using so that I can provide the proper PN logging enable docs link.